# wordpress links keep appending the URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

This is the site i am developing: [www.eleganceandpride.co.nf](http://www.eleganceandpride.co.nf)
The problem is:

All the links have the same issue: when they are clicked they append the current URL instead of producing a brand new URL.

e.g.

**desired:** eleganceandpride.co.nf/design3

**actual:** eleganceandpride.co.nf/!#/design3

This is a huge issue because at times if a form fails to send and you wish to go to another page, instead of putting the **desired** link to that page in the browser, it will just append the current URL and it leads to errors.

Could it be a .htaccess issue?

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like your theme supports Ajax in-page loading of new pages. That's a *feature*; you may be able to turn it off. Not sure what it should do in the case of forms.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you have any idea of how to turn these types of features off, or where to search for them in your theme files?

Comment: Nope, sorry... if nothing is in the theme options, your best bet might be asking the theme's author

Answer (score 0):

Based on past experience with Ajax, you may have ajax page loader plugin turned on. Turn that off. If that isn't the case (and I don't think it is - your theme seems to have ajax built in), you would need to go into the theme options or into the code to turn it off. What theme are you using?